# Easy way to get string pointers

Tags: string, go

A library I am using has a very weird API that often takes string pointers. Currently I am doing this:

```golang
s := "foobar"
weirdFun(&s)
```

to pass strings. Is there a way to do this without the variable?

Comment: afaik its not possible. Docker codebase is doing the same, not sure why. In slack someone suggested to write a helper function that takes a string and returns a pointer to it. So at least you can have a one liner `weirdFun(ps("foobar"))`

Answer (score 2):

The library is really weird, but
you can do this in one line with function wrap, for example

```
func PointerTo[T ~string](s T) *T {
    return &s
}

s := "string"

weirdFun(PointerTo(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Azure SDK uses string pointers to distinguish between no value and the empty string.

Use Azure's [StringPtr](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/to#StringPtr) function to create a pointer to a string literal.

```
import (
    ⋮
    "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/to"
)

⋮
res, err := someClient.Create(ctx, someService.ExampleParameters{
    Location: to.StringPtr(location),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should inform the author of the library, that the strings in Go are already references (to a structure, which is internally represented as a slice of runes), so no expensive copy operation is made by passing string to a function, it's call by reference.
Hope this helps!

Comment: The library is `azure-sdk-for-go`. I have a feeling that it's just poorly auto generated.

Comment: Please, note that a `string` is a `slice` of bytes, not runes.

Comment: There are actual real use cases, not least in the Docker go client module: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/api/types#ImageBuildOptions

Answer (score 0):

The address operation `&x` can be used with *addressable* values.
According to the language [specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized) composite literal.

So, you can work around this using a composite literal:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "text"
    fmt.Printf("value: %v, type: %T\n", &s, &s)
    fmt.Printf("value: %v, type: %T\n", &[]string{"literal"}[0], &[]string{"literal"}[0])
}
```

Even though it's possible I don't recommend using this. This is not an example of clear code.